How to correctly calculate document's type area?
Let's assume I want to construct my document according to Van de Graaf's page construction (Wikipedia; aka. Villard's canon of division). The following conditions apply accordingly:

Paper: A4
Font size: 11pt
Type area: 140mm x 198mm
Head margin: 33mm
Inner margin: 23.333mm
Outer margin: 46.667mm
Foot margin: 66mm

Assuming a page consists of a paragraph running over several pages without illustrations, i.e. pure text, the following message appears after compilation: Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active.
I also know where the underfull \vbox is located: The last line of the first page is not at the bottom of the type area. But I have no idea how to remove the underfull \vbox.
I had read (link 1, link 2) that \textheight should be a multiple of \baselineskip. Why is it that if I replace \textheight = 198mm with \textheight = 47\baselineskip, the error persists?
What options do I have to solve the problem without having to resort to \raggedbottom, packages such as geometry or typearea or changes in the type area? Is there a formula for calculating the type area?
MWE
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[fontsize = 11pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

% === PAPER
\setlength{\paperheight}{297.0mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210.0mm}

% === TEXT
\setlength{\lineskip}{1.0pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{12.0pt}
\setlength{\normalbaselineskip}{12.0pt}
\setlength{\normallineskip}{1.0pt}
\setlength{\normallineskiplimit}{0.0pt}

\setlength{\textheight}{198.0mm} % Not working either: 47\baselineskip
\setlength{\textwidth}{140.0mm}

% === HEADER
\setlength{\headheight}{12.0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{20.0pt}

% === PAGE MARGINS
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.0pt}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.0in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\voffset}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{33.0mm}

\setlength{\topskip}{0.0pt}

% --- EVEN
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.0in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-\hoffset}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{46.667mm}

% --- ODD
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.0in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-\hoffset}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{23.333mm}

% === MARGINALIA
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{100.0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10.0pt}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{7.0pt}

\begin{document}
    \Blindtext[1][7]
\end{document}


Do you know the typearea package?

You want 198 mm for the text height. The normal baseline skip for 11 pt is 13.6 pt.
Now we see that 198 mm is the same as 563.36456 pt. If we subtract the value of 11 pt of \topskip, we can compute
552.36456/13.6 = 40.615
so your document asks for 41 lines per page, but something isn't covered and it's 61% of a line, which is a lot.
I'd use geometry, rather than doing difficult computations by hand.
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=33mm,
  %textheight=198mm,
  lines=42,
  heightrounded,
  inner=23.333mm,
  textwidth=140mm,
  headheight=13.6pt,
  showframe,% for showing the boxes
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}

The recorded value of \textheight is 568.60025 pt, which exceeds 198mm by about 5 pt, that's approximately 1.5 mm.
If you set 41 lines, you finish about 8 pt short.
Nobody would notice, unless they measure with very high precision. Add 0.75 mm at the top and you'll be OK.

Could you explain the \linespread{1.015}?

Perusing through geometry I see hmarginratio, perhaps it should be 1:2 if textwidth is set? (rather than an explicit inner).

@user691586 \linespread remained from a previous attempt. Yes, using hmarginratio and vmarginratio should probably be better.

@egreg Do you know why I get an underfull \vbox when I set \topskip to 0 and use the geometry package or why \topskip is set to 9.23993pt by the geometry package when \lines=42 (Warning: Package geometry Warning: \topskip was changed from 0.0pt to 9.23993pt.)? I know its set to \ht\strutbox when \topskip < \ht\strutbox but why? I dont see a problem for \topskip to be 0 when calculating \textheight via \textheight = (lines − 1) × \baselineskip + \topskip

@Dave Don't set \topskip to zero, if you don't want to be looking for problems.
